# Badges for impact

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, people-reached

In the profile page there is a section where it displays the impact of a user.

[image]

What is the use of this section other than... showing a number?

I propose making this stat at least somewhat useful by adding in badges that are related to the number of people reached, such as a badge for reaching 10k+ people, etc..

Comment: Given how this value is calculated and that it can go both up and down... a badge doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Oded that's worthy of new answer in the original request, none of the answers there at the moment mention this.